# Replacing elements in numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.75, 0.5, 0.21])
one_list = [1] * 3
L_vec = np.diag(one_list)
L_vec[1,0] = a[0]
print(L_vec)
```

Expected Result:

```
[[1,0,0],[0.75,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

Actual Result:

```
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 0 1]]
```

this is the result I got. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

By default dtype for `np.diag` is `int`

convert it into `float` so your float values from array `a` can replace older value

`L_vec = L_vec.astype(float)`

Use below code

```
a = np.array([0.75, 0.5, 0.21])
one_list = [1]*3
L_vec = np.diag(one_list)
L_vec = L_vec.astype(float)

L_vec[1,0] = a[0]
print(L_vec)
```

Output:

```
[[1.   0.   0.  ]
 [0.75 1.   0.  ]
 [0.   0.   1.  ]]
```

You can check datatype using `print(L_vec.dtype)`